# How do I test a conditional in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, conditional-statements

My angular code coverage is failing. I need to test a conditional statement but I am unsure how to go about doing that. The information that I've uncovered online hasn't been very helpful.

**"response.id != -1"** is highlighted yellow so I'm not sure what that means. Everything in the body of the conditional as well as **"this.formGroup.patchValue({"** is highlighted pink meaning it's not covered.

```
 this .service.loadForm().subscribe(response => {

   if(response.id != null && response.id != -1) {
     this.bookName = response.bookName;
     this.bookAuthor = response.bookAuthor;

      this.formGroup.patchValue({
        bookName:this.bookName,
        bookAuthor: this.bookAuthor
        })
      }}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html code coverage report you can mouse hover over the pink and yellow, the text that shows up will tell you why it is highlighted that color.

What you need to do is add additional test cases where the service responds with those values.

```
it('should not update if response id is null' ,() => {
  const service = TestBed.get(ServiceType) as ServiceType;
  const serviceResponse = {id: null, bookName: 'test name', bookAuthor: 'test author'}; // feel free to create the actual object
  service.loadForm = jasmine.createSpy('loadForm).and.returnValue(of(serviceResponse));

  component.loadForm(); // call the function on the component to fire your code

  expect(component.formGroup.controls.bookName).not.toBe(serviceResponse.bookName);
  expect(component.formGroup.controls.bookAuthor).not.toBe(serviceResponse.bookAuthor);
});
```

Then you would have the same test again with except with

```
const serviceResponse = {id: -1, bookName: 'test name', bookAuthor: 'test author'};
```

With those two tests in place you can prove that your if statement successfully prevents the form from being updated when the response has an id of null or -1.

Lastly, it sounds like you haven't added a tests that makes it into your if statement. Your test would look the same as above with these changes listed below.

```
...
const serviceResponse = {id: 100, bookName: 'test name', bookAuthor: 'test author'}; 
...
// removed the .not. so that this will test the value correctl
expect(component.formGroup.controls.bookName).toBe(serviceResponse.bookName);
expect(component.formGroup.controls.bookAuthor).toBe(serviceResponse.bookAuthor);
```

With those three new tests in place your code coverage should indicate all green.